# How to stop user to be logged-in multiple times

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a website with login system in php but one user can be logged in multiple times, so how can i stop it.
My actual code for login

```
SELECT * FROM user where username = '".$username."' and password = '".$password."' ";

    $result=mysqli_query($dbc,$sql);

    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if($count==1){ ...
```

Comment: are you storing any value for logged-in user in php session?

Comment: You may want to read an article about $_SESSION, it could be a good starting point to check if the user is already logged in or not, and if he's logged in, you just don't let him post his login form again.

Answer (score 0):

Is it safe to assume you're setting a session variable with some user identifiable information, such as an ID?

```
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = $row['user_id'];
```

If so, then you could modify your query to check if that user already has an active session.